# yahoo weather change background color by degree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Yahoo Weather problem. I'm trying to change the background color by degrees. For example:

- 10 degrees: Blue
- 11 - 20 degrees: Green
- 21 - 30 degrees: Yellow
- 30 degrees: Red

I'm using this link http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2345795&u=c

http://jsfiddle.net/BJKJT/3/

The `#piece` id is the element that should change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use PHP or some server side code. For example, use simpleXML to parse the file and get the temperature from there. If temp = 20, then background-color:blue